# How to trigger Gitlab CI build locally?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ubuntu-20.04

I've just installed GitLab CI runner locally because I need to debug a build. From the docs is clear how to install it and also how to configure it but it is unclear to me how build is triggered ?

From the docs I've put together:

```
$ gitlab-runner run --debug
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=38298 revision=a998cacd version=13.2.2
Starting multi-runner from /home/mark/.gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...
```

then it launches and seems like it's waiting for something.
But I have no clue as to **how** to trigger it to start building.

How do I go about that ?

**update:**

running `gitlab-runner --debug run exec docker tdd` gives me:

```
...
...
Waiting for stop signal                             builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Starting worker                                     builds=0 worker=0
Dialing: tcp gitlab.com:443 ...                    
Checking for jobs... nothing                        runner=5Y2eis4Q
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file right?

If yes, you just need to execute in the root path of your application folder

`gitlab-runner exec <executor> <step of your pipeline>`

Comment: Yes, my `gitlab-ci.yml` is in `tdd` directory. So I need to run `gitlab-runner run exec docker tdd`, correct ?

Comment: What `<step of your pipeline>` means ? If I need to specify job to build how do I run the whole build not just specified job ?

Comment: To run the entire pipeline locally, you need to register your runner on your gitlab site and changing the tag to your local runner.

Comment: Unfortunately, gitlab-runner exec is deprecated and does not support a lot of functionality